# Mathematical constants

Tags: constants

Am I mistaken, or is there a mistake on the [mathematical constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_constant#cite_note-62) Wikipedia page that describes the Conic constant / [Schwarzschild constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_constant) in terms of Napier's constant?

Comment: What is the mistake you think and what would be the fix?

Comment: Should 'e' be 2.71..., or does it stand for 'eccentricity', or are they one and the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it appears that $e$, which is the eccentricity of a conic section, has been
misinterpreted as  ${\rm e} = 2.71828\ldots$.